# Adjusting Vertical Spacing between a listing and its Caption

Tags: spacing, listings, captions

I am very new to LaTeX.

I am inserting a listing as follows:

```
\lstinputlisting[float=hk,
                 caption=My Caption comes here, 
                 captionpos=b,
                 label=MyLabel]{media/MyFile.xml}
```

*media* is my project directory where all my files and images are stored. One of those files is *MyFile.xml* which is a code snippet.

The problem is the caption of this listing is very close to it. I would like to add some spacing between the two of them.

Any pointers?

Comment: Try `\lstinputlisting[belowskip=4ex, ...]`

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your reply. I tried your recomondation but noticed the spacing between the listing(plus its caption) and the paragraph following the listing is affected. Still couldn't move the caption away from the listing vertically. Thank you once again though. Any ideas?

Comment: abovecaptionskip did it for me :D!!

Comment: @Daniel could you perhaps write up your comment as an answer so that we can close this question?

Comment: @Seamus: Sure, done.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

The documentation of the [`listing`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package lists a number of key-val options to affect the spacing between the listing, its caption, and the surrounding material:

- `aboveskip=<dim>`, `belowskip=<dim>` (default: `\medskipamount`) specify the vertical space above (respectively, below) the listing *including its caption*.
- `abovecaptionskip=<dim>`, `belowcaptionskip=<dim>` (default: `\smallskipamount`) specify the vertical space above (respectively, below) the listing's caption. Depending on `\captionpos=<t|b>` either one has to be used to increase the vertical space between the listing and its caption.