# Adjust vertical spacing between caption and listing in KOMA (scrartcl)

Tags: captions, koma-script, minted, code

In the standard article class the distance between caption and the listing below it is fine. But when using KOMA-Script's documentclass `scrartcl` the vertical space is too big (see the image below). I'm using `minted` package and the code is inside `listing` environment.

**Q: What is the easiest way to adjust the vertical spacing between the caption and the floating listing?**

If that can be achieved without using `listing` environment, that is also fine. And here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
\caption{Code sample}
\begin{minted}[frame=lines]{js}
function foo() {
  return;
}
\end{minted}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

[image: Too much vertical space below caption]

PS. I have identical problem with figures where the caption is too far *below* the figure. That might be a related case.

EDIT: I have tried to fix this using caption package with no luck. I have no idea where to look next.

EDIT2: I know some programming. So if there is a way to redefine some KOMA macros, I'd like to try it. But I don't know where to start debugging...

Comment: As it seems there is an option for listings, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61413/4736 Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hmm, not sure that'll help. I'm not using [`listings`](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package but `listing` environment which (I guess) is provided by `minted`package. I also tried adding `captions` package but various skip parameters moved both the listing and the caption.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot reproduce your example image. With `scrartcl` the distance I get is very consistent comparing, e.g., tables with headings:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
\caption{Code sample}
\begin{minted}[frame=lines]{js}
function foo() {
  return;
}
\end{minted}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

[image: example with table and listing]

Nevertheless, `minted` with option `newfloat` uses package [`newfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat), that is part of the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) bundle. You can use `caption` to configure the captions of the `listing` environment, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[listing]{position=top,skip=-10pt}% move caption of listing toward listing

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
\caption{Code sample}
\begin{minted}[frame=lines]{js}
function foo() {
  return;
}
\end{minted}
\end{listing}

\captionsetup[listing]{position=top,skip=10pt}% move caption away from caption
\begin{listing}
\caption{Code sample}
\begin{minted}[frame=lines]{js}
function foo() {
  return;
}
\end{minted}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It fixed my problem, thanks!!!!!